# unable to open chrome browser in jenkins for selenium script

Tags: jenkins, selenium-webdriver, jenkins-plugins

I created a testing framework in using Selenium WebDriver and i want to launch chrome browser, it is working fine as i run the same via eclipse, but it thorws below error when i try to run the same script via jenkins:-

Error:-

```
 T E S T S
-------------------------------------------------------
Running TestSuite
Starting ChromeDriver 2.24.417431 (9aea000394714d2fbb20850021f6204f2256b9cf) on port 45706
Only local connections are allowed.
```

and my code to launch browser is:-

```
public class BrowserSelection {
    public static WebDriver driver; 
    public FileInputStream fis;
    public static File file;

    public static Properties prop;
    public String username;
    public String password;
    public static XSSFWorkbook wb;
    public static XSSFSheet ws;
    public static WebDriverWait wait;
    public static Screen src;
    public static Pattern prn;




    @BeforeSuite()
    public void browser() throws Exception{
        //property file load
        prop=new Properties();
        file=new File(System.getProperty("user.dir")+"\\src\\main\\resources\\config\\config.properties");
        fis=new FileInputStream(file);
        prop.load(fis);
        //excel file load
        fis=new FileInputStream(System.getProperty("user.dir")+"\\src\\main\\resources\\excel\\data.xlsx");
        wb=new XSSFWorkbook(fis);

        file=new File("D:\\LoyalityFiles\\");
        //File[] dir_contents=file.listFiles();


        if (prop.getProperty("browser").equalsIgnoreCase("firefox")) {
            /*ProfilesIni profile=new ProfilesIni();
            FirefoxProfile myprofile=profile.getProfile(prop.getProperty("firefoxprofilename"));*/
            FirefoxProfile myprofile=new FirefoxProfile();
            myprofile.setPreference("browser.download.dir",prop.getProperty("firefoxfilesave"));
            myprofile.setPreference("browser.download.folderList", 2);  
            myprofile.setPreference("browser.helperApps.neverAsk.saveToDisk", "application/zip");               
            driver=new FirefoxDriver(myprofile);

        }else if (prop.getProperty("browser").equalsIgnoreCase("chrome")) {

            System.setProperty("Webdriver.chrome.driver",System.getProperty("user.dir")+prop.getProperty("chromeexe"));
            Map<String, Object> prefs = new HashMap<String, Object>();
            prefs.put("download.default_directory", prop.getProperty("chromefileSave"));

            DesiredCapabilities caps = DesiredCapabilities.chrome();

            ChromeOptions options = new ChromeOptions();
            options.setExperimentalOption("prefs", prefs);
            options.addArguments("--disable-extensions");
            caps.setCapability(ChromeOptions.CAPABILITY, options);

            driver=new ChromeDriver(caps);
        }       

        driver.get(prop.getProperty("testURL"));        
        //driver.manage().window().maximize();
        driver.manage().window().setSize(new Dimension(1366, 768));
        driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(30, TimeUnit.SECONDS);    

    }
```

*This is maven based project.

i think Jenkins is not able to set the chrome exe path. pls suggest!! how to solve this.....

Comment: https://wiki.jenkins.io/display/JENKINS/Step+by+step+guide+to+set+up+master+and+slave+machines+on+Windows?focusedCommentId=59510810

Answer (score 1):

Most likely, this has nothing to do with your Selenium tests and the Chrome browser path, but with the Jenkins slaves and Chrome browser itself.
Correct me if I'm wrong, but your Jenkins is running the slaves from a Windows Service and try to open the Chrome browser. This means that you have your Chrome process started as a sub-process of the Jenkins Windows Service and Chrome is trying to move away from this (aka Chrome will not works correctly in Session 0).

There is also a bug logged [here](https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=615396) where you can read more.

I also encountered this for my TFS ran tests, where the Test Agent was set up as Windows service and the solution was to set it as a process.

So the easiest solution would be to set Jenkins as a process, not a Service.

Comment: Is there a way you can set the chrome options to run as a process rather than a subprocess?